# comparing things that are long to tell?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, comparative-constructions, comparison

In the following sentence I am comparing two things:

> There is no comparison between a solicitor who works in a lower court
> in countries like Australia and Britain and an advocate in a US court
> of law.

Sides of comparison are:

1. Solicitors who work in lower courts in countries like Australia and Britain
2. Advocates in US courts of law.

Is it clear in  the sentence that I am comparing these? I guess the length of phrases can cause ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In his book *Style*, Joseph Williams offers this very useful advice for elements in a series:

> try to order the elements so that they go from shorter to longer, from simpler to more complex.

Here, the result would look like this:

> There is no comparison between an advocate in a US court of law and a solicitor who works in a lower court in countries like Australia and Britain.

It's a lot easier to grasp. One reason is that it places the headwords of the noun phrases (**advocate** and **solicitor**) closer together. The reader can perceive the relationships more easily.

Obviously, there will be situations where you have to put the longer element sooner. For example, you might need to arrange ideas in order of importance. But this is a useful guideline if you are free to arrange the ideas for maximum readability.

Answer (score 0):

A typographic device to help the reader is to emphasise the nouns that you are comparing.  This can be done unobtrusively with italics

> There is no comparison between a *solicitor* who works in a lower court in countries like Australia and Britain and an *advocate* in a US court of law.